# Select unique value on one column within multiple table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the below as a result of my query. Please note that this is on multiple tables.

```
EMAIL(A)  PROD_ID(B)   PROD_NAME(B)   CODE(C)
a@a.com   123456       SUNLIGHT A     002
a@a.com   123456       SUNLIGHT B     002
a@a.com   123456       SUNLIGHT C     002
a@a.com   768901       MOON           003
a@a.com   881231       STAR           004
```

My query is as below.

```
SELECT A.EMAIL, B.PROD_ID, B.PROD_NAME, C.CODE
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.EMAIL = A.EMAIL
INNER JOIN C ON C.CODE = B.CODE
GROUP BY A.EMAIL, B.PROD_ID, B.PROD_NAME, C.CODE
ORDER BY A.EMAIL, C.CODE
```

I need to get only 1 row of data per `PROD_ID`. I tried using `MAX(B.PROD_ID) AS "PROD_ID"`but I still get multiple row for `PROD_ID`. Can anyone suggest something on this? Or help me out? Many thanks!

The desired result is:

```
EMAIL(A)  PROD_ID(B)   PROD_NAME(B)   CODE(C)
a@a.com   123456       SUNLIGHT A     002
a@a.com   768901       MOON           003
a@a.com   881231       STAR           004
```

Any help is appreciated. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collapse/aggregate PROD_NAME somehow. I used MIN since it matchas your desired result. You can use whatever aggregate fits to you:

```
SELECT A.EMAIL, B.PROD_ID, MIN(B.PROD_NAME), C.CODE
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.EMAIL = A.EMAIL
INNER JOIN C ON C.CODE = B.CODE
GROUP BY A.EMAIL, B.PROD_ID, C.CODE
ORDER BY A.EMAIL, C.CODE
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to use MAX not knowing MIN will do the trick. :) Many thanks!

Comment: I think this query won't work properly in case when column EMAIL will contain different values.

Comment: I don't think so.   If you will use MIN or MAX for other columns (EMAIL, CODE) then values of these columns will be mixed from different rows.